# Getting JSON data from callback on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using a plug-in that uploads, crops and resizes images and then spits out a callback in JSON format that looks similar to the following :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "action": "crop",
  "folder": "/podart",
  "size": "1606947",
  "oldName": "ALL-KEYS.jpg",
  "extension": "jpg",
  "mime": "image/jpeg",
  "isImage": "true",
  "name": "e6a4272ae328d9906908199dc7243aeb.jpg",
  "coords": {
            "x": "300",
            "y": "300",
            "width": "2400",
            "height": "2400",
            "rotate": "0"
  },
    "copies": [
        {
          "success": true,
          "folder": "/podart/medium",
          "name": "e6a4272ae328d9906908199dc7243aeb.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is all done on the same page without any reloads.

How do I access the [copies] [folder]+[name] data and echo that out in an IMG tag?

I know how to do it with PHP but I can't use PHP here as the page is already rendered before this data arrives, so I guess I have to use JS or jQuery, which is where I am lost.

I read something about "scoping" the data but I couldn't really understand how to implement it. Also that referred to JSON being loaded, not rendered on the same page. I only need to display this image after this JSON data is received.

Comment: So you have a bit of javascript that has that JSON in an object? Basically the callback should be calling a success handler on your page returning that object. From there you can access the data using simple bean path notation <your object>.copies.folder  etc etc

Comment: Hmm, ok like I said, this is a plug-in (http://codecanyon.net/item/get-file-uploader-cropper-sizes-and-image-format/8765349) so I'm not really sure how it's handling everything. The docs are great but don't cover what I'm trying to do at all.

Comment: The issue with answering this question is we don't know what you have or how this plugin works at all. The documentation should explain how to put the plugin on your page and make it work, I'm assuming you have the plugin working?

Comment: Also, since you have already spent money on it, you might as well ask the provider for support [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/get-file-uploader-cropper-sizes-and-image-format/8765349/support) instead of asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: @vove I have already asked the plug-in author but this is something that I want to learn about for myself and not just get an answer to for this specific issue. This is bound to come up again in the future and I'd like to know how to deal with it.

Comment: I've never had to deal with callbacks in this way before so I need to learn how to deal with them.

Comment: That's how you learn to be honest. He will point out the error, you analyze it and memorize it...

Comment: I know what you are saying, but I tried to google for an answer to this before even contacting him. I couldn't find anything that seemed to be what I was looking for except the scoping thing I mentioned. Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology? That's why I'm here on stack, to learn!

Comment: Ok I found JSON.parse(), I think this might be my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself through trial and error.

In case anybody else is wondering, in the response I can access it like this :

```
var cropped = ("http://www.website.com" + data.copies[0].folder + "\/" + data.copies[0].name);
$('#myimage').html("<img src=" + cropped + " />");
```